# Android: okhttp3 > crash: Unexpected TLS version: NONE

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I've integrated `retrofit2` since couple of months ago; there were no problem until yesterday with an user (Huawei, model MHA-L29, on Android 7.0):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected TLS version: NONE
       at okhttp3.TlsVersion.forJavaName(TlsVersion.java:53)
       at okhttp3.Handshake.get(Handshake.java:56)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:300)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

In my `Gradle` :

> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

Have you got some ideas about this crash? Is there a link with `Retrofit`? I didn't add `OkHttp library` in my `Gradle`, I must do it?

Comment: share your code where you call OkHttp?

Comment: Is it working fine on another nougat devices?

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya : yes

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this by providing TLS configuration I am not sure if this will work. referred from [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS)

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
        .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
        .cipherSuites(
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
        .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .build();
```

Comment: By default Okhttp uses MODERN_TLS.

Comment: I did that, but sometimes this crash appears yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error was resoult in 3.11.0 version.You can see a answer about this question here: [Android: okhttp3 > crash: Unexpected TLS version: NONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766225/android-okhttp3-crash-unexpected-tls-version-none)